# SQL: How to select year and month when customer's turnover was the biggest?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to List top 10 customers by average monthly transactions amount turnover, in
additional column indicating the year and month with highest monthly turnover of the customer.

I made the first part - list top 10 customers by average monthly transactions amount turnover.

```sql
Select column1, AVG(Case when when column1="x" then column2
                      when column1="y" then column2
                      when column1="z" then column2
                      when column1="q" then column2 End)/12 [AVG]
from table1
Group by column1
Order by AVG DESC;
```

How to make the second part of the task - in
additional column indicating the year and month with highest monthly turnover of the customer?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like aggregation and window functions.  Date functions are notoriously database-dependent, but the idea is:

```
select ymc.*
from (select year(r_date) as yyyy, month(r_date) as mm, c_id, sum(amount) as amount,
             row_number() over (partition by c_id order by sum(amount) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by year(r_date), month(r_date), c_id
     ) ymc
where seqnum = 1;
```

Not all databases support `year()` and `month()` but all have similar functionality.  So you may need to modify for what your database uses.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query, below query in for Oracle, tag your database so that can provide appropriate query.

```
select c_id, to_char(r_date, 'MM'), to_char(r_date, 'YYYY'), max(amount)
group by c_id, to_char(r_date, 'MM'), to_char(r_date, 'YYYY');
```